# Move data from Cursor to PageFragment

Tags: android, cursor, page-fragments

I' ve a troble with moving data from `Cursor` to `PageFragment`.
I read all data from `Cursor`, but in `PageFragment` goes only last value.
So positions go ahead(0,1,2,..), but from cursor it goes only last one.

How can I solve this problem?

HELP, please!

```
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {      
          while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            GlobalVars.ditty = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_DIT));          
          }                         
return PageFragment.newInstance(position, GlobalVars.ditty);        
}

public static class GlobalVars {
       public static String ditty;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read all data from Cursor, but in PageFragment goes only last value

Because inside while loop you are assigning new value to `GlobalVars.ditty` in each iteration so either append new value to `GlobalVars.ditty` with separator or use any data structure to store values like ArrayList,HashMap,... :

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            GlobalVars.ditty += 
               cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_DIT));          
          }
```

Comment: Thank you for help! I did this way. But all data from Cursor go in one value, in one position. But I need to take first value from Cursor with first position, second from Cursor with second position. Do you know how to do this way?

Comment: @tadvas : see my answer i also mention if you want separate values then use ArrayList instead of String